# Trying to pass a value to a model using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Trying to learn Coedigniter here and struggling a little bit from the start. I basically want to create a query in my model using a value in the url.

Controller (Customer.php)

```
public function customer_edit($id) {
    $this->load->model( 'Customers_model' ); //loads model
    $data[ 'results' ] = $this->Customers_model->edit_customers($id);
    $this->load->view( 'customers/customer_edit', $data );
}
```

Model (customers_model.php)

```
public function edit_customers($id)//This function returns an array
{
$this->load->database('default', TRUE); //connect to database
$this->db->where(['idcustomers'=>$id]); //creates where statement from url
$query = $this->db->get('customers');//create query
return $query->result_array(); //creates array from query
}
```

View (customer_edit.php)

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtfname" value="<?php echo $results['fname'];?>">
  </div>
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtlname" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

When I go to http://blahblah.com/customers/customer_edit/454 I get the following error:

Message: Undefined index: fname

Filename: customers/customer_edit.php

Line Number: 10

This is what I know:
On other pages where I am just displaying all the records in a table it works fine so I am not having a database connection problem. fname and idcustomers are the correct column names in the database.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: it just says undefined index, is `fname` defined?  maybe you need a `foreach`? `print_r($results)` in your view to find out

Comment: return $query->first_row(‘array’); it will return one record only

Comment: Mohd Alomar - Message: Use of undefined constant ‘array’ - assumed '‘array’'

Comment: Hey Ghost - print_r($results) returned Array ( [0] => Array ( [idcustomers] => 454 [fname] => YUN ) )

Comment: Hey Ghost - Doing the foreach on the view did it. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @phishyman2 as a side note, you could use `$query->row_array();` for a single record selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem. I added a foreach at the beginning of the form like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtfname" value="<?php echo ucwords(strtolower($object['fname']));?>">
  </div>
```

Thanks Ghost for helping answer this question.

Comment: I think you kind of left out the whole foreach thing.  If you know you are only going to get one single row ( as everyone has stated in other comments ) you can simply use row_array() instead result_array() and ditch the whole foreach thing completely... you need to understand what format you are getting from the database - a Single array (row_result) or an array of arrays (result_array) which your print_r clearly showed you.

Comment: TimBrownlaw - Thank you very much. That was much easier. Worked great.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Except where I've written row_result should be row_array... Can't edit it to fix it :(